# Apache serve single page application alongside WSGI process with AliasMatch

Tags: regex, apache, single-page-application, wsgi, npm-live-server

I would like to configure my Apache web server to serve both a single page application, as well as a WSGI process. I can successfully serve the WSGI app at `/api` using this config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp threads=5 user=apache
WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/html/myapp/setup/myapp.wsgi
```

As such, if a user hits `/api/things` the JSON data from my WSGI app (flask) is sent over.

And my home `index.html` file (which is served when the user hits `/`) works when including this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp/myappweb/public
```

However, when a user visits any route that does not start with `/api` I would like my Apache web server to serve up `index.html`. For example, if the user hits `/things` or `/things/42` I would like Apache to send them to `index.html` instead of throwing a 404. (I am using redux-router to handle the client-side paths.)

I got this to work in my dev environment using the node live-server package with this flag:

```
live-server --entry-file=index.html
```

Additionally, I can use `AliasMatch` to force all routes starting with `/things` to show `index.html`:

```
AliasMatch "^/things(/.*)?$" /var/www/html/myapp/myappweb/public/index.html
```

But what I really want is an `AliasMatch` regex that forces all routes, except for anything starting with `/api/`, to display `index.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

```
RewriteRule ^((?!\/[api|lib]).)*$ /var/www/html/myapp/myappweb/public/index.html
```

I needed to exclude both the `api` dir as well as the `lib` dir (where my js/css files are hosted).